# Middleware for each route server side in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to figure out a way to have some code run on initial page load for each request. I want to be able to identify the request domain and redirect to a specific part of the website based on it.

From what I can understand I could add `getInitialProps` to a custom `_app` page but that would disable all optimization from next. Also `_app` doesn't seem to support `getServerSideProps` which I considered as an alternative.

Another way I thought about doing it was to have `getServerSideProps` in each page of the website with the check I have to do, but this would make every page rerender on server side for each new request, disabling rendering at build time even for pure static pages.

Is there any other solution I can adopt?

**EDIT**

Basically I need the request object so that I can do something like this:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({
  req
}) => {
  if (req.headers.host === 'something') {
     return {
       redirect: {
         permanent: false,
         destination: "/"
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide 1 example of what you are exactly trying to do?

Comment: Added a simple example

Comment: How many pages you want to apply that change to? All of them/some of them? What would be exact number?

Comment: All of them, don't have a precise number, but if a new page gets added it should have that check too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Next.js [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#header-cookie-and-query-matching) in your `next.config.js` file.

```js
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/(.+)',
                has: [
                    {
                        type: 'header',
                        key: 'host',
                        value: 'something'
                    }
                ],
                permanent: false,
                destination: '/'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This rule will match any path that's not `/`, and redirect if it contains the desired `host` header value.

Comment: I don't think this fits my use case. The value of the host is dynamic

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti I guess you forgot to mention that. Is the value known at build time? And wouldn't you have the same problem if you were to do it with `getServerSideProps` as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Wait I guess your solution could work if there is a way to negate the `has`. Like can I redirect if host is not 'something' which is known at build time?

Comment: The `value` can be a regex like string, so you could use that to match if `host` is _not_  `'something'`.

Comment: I'll try and report back. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could try using something like `^(?!something).*$` which uses negative lookahead. Will match anything that does _not_ contain `something` as a substring.

Answer (score 0):

I would put solutions to this in the order below:

1. do redirect on your server(nginx or something), fastest solution
2. you could create custom [Next.js server][1] to handle redirect
3. custom App as you said
4. RouteGuard used in each page which would redirect